# Joomla link to category list

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Hi all, I have encountered a problem with Joomla.

There is a custom html module with link inside. Link goes to menu item, which is category list. As soon as I understand, I have to copy the following code from the link attribute of the menu item and paste it inside href.

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=12
```

But it doesn't work this way. The 404 Error Page appears.

How to make this link work properly?

Thank you.

Comment: And when you click on that menu item does it work? What's the difference in the url with this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a menu item linking to the category list, then when you preview it in the frontend, right click the menu item and click "Copy Link Location".
Then paste the link within the `href=""` and remove the `http://example.com` bit so it starts with `index.php?com_content......`

The reason why I say this is because the url you are using must be incorrect.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. But it's not the exact solution I am looking for.

Comment: @KseniaMurach - creating the menu item is only to get the correct URL for the href="" tag. You can delete the menu item after you have got the URL.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was tired, misunderstood you. Thank you for your help, the problem is solved.